# Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed occurring after fix put in for connection pool issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-pooling, using-statement

The site I maintain was built with ASP Webforms. I was not involved in building it. Since upgrading the server where it is hosted we started seeing a lot of the following error:
**"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all of pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached"**

The fix suggestions that I found online were to put DB connection requests in the following format, with a using() statement. But this has had a knock on effect

**CertificationsSkillsDB.cs**

```
        public SqlDataReader GetCertifications(int userID)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]);
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();

                using (myConnection)
                {
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("GetCertifications", myConnection);
                    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter parameterUserID = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int);
                    parameterUserID.Value = userID;
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterUserID);

                    SqlDataReader result = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                log.Error("Timesheets error when populating Certifications and Skills grids");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

My datagrid looks like this:
**CertificationsSkills.aspx.**

```
           <asp:datagrid
                            id="CertDataGrid"
                            runat="server"
                            boderstyle="None"
                            font-names="Verdana"
                            font-size="8pt"
                            bordercolor="#CCCCCC"
                            backcolor="White"
                            width="100%"
                            font-name="Verdana"
                            borderwidth="1px"
                            autogeneratecolumns="False"
                            datakeyfield="certificateItemID"
                            onitemdatabound="CertDataGrid_ItemDataBound"
                            ondeletecommand="CertDataGrid_Delete"
                            onupdatecommand="CertDataGrid_Update"
                            oncancelcommand="CertDataGrid_Cancel"
                            oneditcommand="CertDataGrid_Edit"
                            headerstyle-backcolor="#aaaadd"
                            cellpadding="3">
                            <SelectedItemStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#669999"></SelectedItemStyle>
                            <ItemStyle ForeColor="#000066"></ItemStyle>
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#333399"></HeaderStyle>
                            <FooterStyle ForeColor="#000066" BackColor="White"></FooterStyle>
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:EditCommandColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ButtonType="LinkButton" UpdateText="<img src='images/ok.gif' class='updateCertImg' alt='Update Entry' border='0' height='16' width='16'/>"
                                    CancelText="<img src='images/trash.gif' alt='Cancel Update' border='0' height='16' width='16'/>" EditText="<img src='images/edit.gif' class='editCertImg' alt='Edit' border='0' height='16' width='16'/>">
                                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:EditCommandColumn>
                                <asp:ButtonColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Text="<img src='images/trash.gif' alt='Delete' border='0' height='16' width='16'/>"
                                CommandName="Delete">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:ButtonColumn>

                                <asp:BoundColumn Visible="false" DataField="certificateItemID" SortExpression="certificateItemID" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Certificate Item ID">
                                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:BoundColumn>

                                <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="certificateName" ItemStyle-CssClass="certificateName" HeaderText="Certificate Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "certificateName") %>' ID="Label1" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>

                                <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="certificateExpiry" ItemStyle-CssClass="certificateExpiry" HeaderText="Certificate Expiry">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "certificateExpiry") %>' ID="Label2"/>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:TextBox ID="Edit_dtCertifcateExpiry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/calendar_icon.gif" />
                                        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="Edit_dtCertifcateExpiry" PopupButtonID="calImgStart"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                            </Columns>
                            </asp:datagrid>
```

**CertificationSkills.aspx.cs** page looks like this:

```
        public void BindGrid()
        {

            // reload the cert and skills grid

            try
            {
                //  lookup up certifications for this user and bind them to the Certification grid
                int userID = SessionState.UserID;
                CertDataGrid.DataSource = certificationsSkillsDB.GetCertifications(userID);
                CertDataGrid.DataBind();


                //  lookup up skills for this user and bind them to the grid
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                log.Error("error when populating Certifications and Skills grids");
                Message.InnerHtml = "ERROR: There was a problem loading Certifications and Skills entries";
                Message.Style["color"] = "red";
            }

        }



        public void CertDataGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
        {

            //  if EDIT. 
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
            {
                System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord drv = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Item.DataItem;
                String certificeItemID = drv["certificateItemID"].ToString();
                String certificateName = drv["certificateName"].ToString();
                String certificateExpiry = drv["certificateExpiry"].ToString();

                //Edit_dtCertifcateExpiry.Value = certificateExpiry;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(certificateExpiry))
                {
                    ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("Edit_dtCertifcateExpiry")).Text = certificateExpiry;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("Edit_dtCertifcateExpiry")).Text = certificateExpiry.Substring(0, 10);
                }


            }
        }



BindGrid runs first but then CertDataGrid_ItemDataBound is run and it throws the error 
**Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.**
(CertDataGrid_ItemDataBound is only paritally built and more needs to go into it)

I understand that that the **using* statement is closing the connection but I'm not sure how to get around this without the original **connection pool** issue occurring.

Any ideas?
```

Comment: _DataTable result = new DataTable(); result.Load(myCommand.ExecuteReader()); return result;_ of course change the return type.

Comment: Thanks @Steve
That appears to have worked.
I had to make a small change to CertDataGrid_ItemDataBound in order for editing to work
```System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord drv = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Item.DataItem;```

needed to be changed to 

```System.Data.DataRowView drv = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;```

Comment: Correct, I would also change the using statement placing it directly on the SqlConnection creation and include in the try/catch also the open.